# Finding all functions that satisfy $yf(x)-xf(y)<0,~\forall x>y$

Tags: functions, inequality

I want to find functions that satisfies $$yf(x)-xf(y)<0,~\forall x,y\in(0,1)~s.t.~x>y,$$

where $0\leq f(z)\leq 1,~\forall z\in(0,1).$

My attempt went like this...

Because the inequality is the same as $\frac{f(x)}{f(y)}<\frac{x}{y}$, when $y$ approaches to zero, the value on the right-hand side approaches to the infinity. Thus, we should have $\lim_{z\rightarrow0}f(z)=0$ as well as $f(z)<z$ for all $z\in(0,1)$.

And then I tried several concave functions that have $f(0)=0$ and $f(z)<z$ and they all seem to satisfy the inequality, but I could not formally prove that any concave function $f$ with $f(0)=0$ and $f(z)<z$ satisfies the inequality.

So, my question is under what condition on $f$ does the inequality is satisfied? Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Concave functions with $f(0) = 0$ do have that property, because the slope of the line joining $(0, 0)$ with $(x, f(x))$ decreases with increasing $x$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It makes more sense to consider the function $g(x)=f(x)/x$. Then, the condition is simply
$$yf(x)-xf(y)<0\Leftrightarrow yf(x)<xf(y)\Leftrightarrow g(x)<g(y).$$
So, $g$ must be a decreasing function. The condition that $0\leq f(z)\leq 1$ is tantamount to
$$0\leq zg(z)\leq 1\Leftrightarrow 0\leq g(z)\leq 1/z.$$
So, for every decreasing function $g(z)$ on $(0,1)$ that is bounded above by $1/z$, the property is satisfied for $f(z)=zg(z)$. Such a function need not be convex, concave, or even continuous.

Comment: Thanks! So simple and intuitive!